# Making files on a server appear as local files on a user's computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, filesystems, synchronization

Since I do not have any starting point to this problem, I can't share my research with you guys. However, I'll try my best to make the context as clear as possible.

I am relatively new to Node.js and Javascript but have invested many hours per day to learn their basics up to the point where I know how to manipulate the DOM model on the client side and the concept of event loop & callbacks on node.js (I implemented the RabbitMQ protocol with my own version of publisher and subscriber to a custom exchange using node.js).

With this information in mind, I have been asked by my employer to create a service in which the files on a server appear on the user's computer as if it belonged on the local file system. This module is to be developed as a part of a larger application in which the above mentioned implementation of Rabbit MQ is also a part.(The Rabbit MQ layer is responsible for carrying messages from server to client). As an analogy, you can think this as the DropBox App for syncing from Windows. Any ideas,resources and pointers to the starting point will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Are you supposed to do this in JavaScript? 2. Can you run node.js both on the server and on the client computer?

Comment: @Siguza No I'm not supposed to do it in JS but the rest of my implementation is in JS so it kind of limits the options. And yes I can

Answer (score 0):

Ankit,

Here, you will have to treat node.js as a "network server", and not simply as a "Web Server". Node.JS at its heart is a network server aimed at handling high performance i/O tasks, and allowing you to use Javascript to do that.

Web Server is a type of network server that is implemented by modules on top of node such as express.

You need to use some file i/o related node modules for this, along with socket.io for your task.

Comment: So that means I use the node.js implementation of a server to somehow get files from an Apache Server. Then use my existing framework to handle the task, right?

Comment: Not really. What do you have on client side ? A browser or you are expected to integrate it with say - windows explorer (not IE) like Samba does - say be able to map as a drive? So not sure where Apache Server (httpd) comes in here.

Comment: On the client side is a website which has a collection of files. I have to show them mapped on a drive in Windows Explorer, much like you see the dropbox folder upon installing their app. I guess Apache won't be doing anything for this.

Comment: Do you need node.js on both the sides? It seems as of now you have an only have an experimental client module smb2 for node, that will allow you to talk to a SMB server like Samba at the other end. Which means you can have your client in node.js, but not ther server. Implementing a SMB server over node.js is a different game altogether.

Comment: So do you have any suggestions on how to approach this problem?